# What time of day is the best time to play Star Wars Battlefront?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I just bought the game and this is my first time ever playing online multiplayer games. As I live in Asia, I am concerned about time zone differences. Waiting for a full game (before it can start) is time wasted since I can't alt-tab to another program to do something else in case I miss the start of the match, or get kicked for being inactive. I can do effectively nothing on the com staying on the same screen while waiting, so I want to minimise my waiting downtime during the timeslot I allocate to this game.

What timezones are you guys from, and what time of day is Star Wars Battlefront most active for you? Does the day of the week and whether it's a holiday matter?

Comment: I changed the tag to mean the new Battlefront, not the 2004 one. I assume that's what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not own the game but as this is an issue for many other games i will try to answer.

Use [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/) website/map to determine your own time zone.
You said Asia but this can variate from +5 to +10.
Central Europa is hour 0, most of the USA area's are at -5 to -10.

This means you need to look for the peek times in those area's.

- On weekdays this is between 18:00 and 23:00
- Saturday and Sunday this should be between 10:00 and 23:00
- Holidays are more difficult to say, some holidays keep people away from their games, others give them more time to play.
- General school vacations can be considered as weekend days.

Now all you need to do is calculate the amount of hours between your time zone and one of your two target zone's (USA & Europe).

Spoiler alert, you'll probably end up in times that are not ideal for yourself.
If you want to play in the European peek time, you'll need to add the amount of time until you are in your own time zone.

Lets say you are at +6; then your best chance for a heavy population in the game will be between 23:00 and 05:00 (not the best hours for someone with a regular life of work, education and family).
If you want to aim at a USA peek time you'll need to add another 6-8 hours.
This means you should play between 07:00 and 14:00. (again, not a great time of day)

All of this is from my own experience in years of online gaming from a European zone.
I hope this helps you at least a little bit.

Another option to help you is joining a clan or guild (or whatever it is called in SW:BF).
This will increase the amount of people you start a search with and will help you find a game quicker as there will be less need for *'random'* people to join.

Comment: Pretty comprehensive and well thought answer given the unusual nature of the question. +1 for the sheer effort